# Magento get product details in order collection

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

How to get Orderd Product name,sku,qty etc in order collection Magento

```
<?php
class MPS_Ordermail_Model_Observer{ 
    public function Test($event){
        //do something
        Mage::log("Testing success...........",null,'custom.log');
        $ordershippeddays = 7; // number of days you want
        $fromDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", gmmktime(0, 0, 0, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d") - $ordershippeddays, gmdate("Y")));
        $toDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", gmmktime(23, 59, 59, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d"), gmdate("Y")));

         $ordercollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate))
        ->load();

        count($ordercollection);


        foreach ($ordercollection as $orderkey => $ordervalue) {
        $eid = $ordervalue->getOrderId();   
        $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($eid);
        Mage::log("Testing success...........");
        Mage::log($customerorderid = $order->getIncrementId());
        Mage::log($customeremailid = $order->getCustomerEmail());
        Mage::log($customername   = $order->getCustomerFirstname());
        Mage::log($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle());
        Mage::log($order->getStatusLabel());
        $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
        Mage::log($billingAddress->getStreetFull());
        Mage::log($billingAddress->getRegion());
        Mage::log($billingAddress->getCountry());
        Mage::log($billingAddress->getPostcode());
        Mage::log($billingAddress->getTelephone());
        Mage::log($shipping_address->getStreetFull());
        Mage::log($shipping_address->getRegion());
        Mage::log($shipping_address->getCountry());
        Mage::log($shipping_address->getPostcode());
        Mage::log($shipping_address->getTelephone());
        Mage::log($orderTotalValue = number_format ($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.' , $thousands_sep = ''));

        }





    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `foreach ($ordercollection as $orderkey => $ordervalue) {` add this

```
foreach ($ordervalue->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $sku = $item->getSku();
    $name = $item->getName();
    $qty = $item->getOrderedQty();
}
```